# No module named 'airflow.providers.amazon.aws.hooks.redshift

Tags: airflow, amazon-redshift

Using Airflow 2.5.1, reinstalled in virtualenv in Python AWS provider but this problem persists:

```
from airflow.providers.amazon.aws.hooks.redshift import  
   RedshiftHook ModuleNotFoundError: No module named'airflow.providers.amazon.aws.hooks.redshift'
```

while using

```
from airflow.providers.amazon.aws.hooks.redshift import RedshiftHook
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all list providers to see if AWS provider is installed:

```
airflow providers list
```

After that list hooks to see what hook is supported by your provider:

```
airflow providers hooks
```

Turns out that actual  hook is

```
airflow.providers.amazon.aws.hooks.redshift_sql.RedshiftSQLHook
```

and then you call it with:

```
 hook = RedshiftSQLHook(redshift_conn_id='redshift_ddq')
```

Comment: I assume you upgraded directly from `apache-airflow-providers-amazon<2.6.0` to `apache-airflow-providers-amazon>=6.0.0` this is why you missed the deprecation warning for the class/file that was added in `2.6.0`. Version `5.0.0` removed many deprecated classes among with redshift. if you are bumping over several major releases it's best to go through the change log so you can verify you are not missing important updates